Why is "review" the answer to the crossword clue "entertainment"?
I just moved from normal to hard in an online crossword game today, and one clue was simply 'entertainment'.
The answer turned out to be 'review' and I have no idea how that links using the standard crossword logic which was effectively synonyms.
What am I missing?
For attribution purposes, the app is called 'English Crossword puzzle'. From Google play: http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appspot.orium_blog.crossword.eng&utm_source=promo

This doesn't seem like a cryptic clue. Can you link the puzzle or attach a picture?

@BenjaminWang it's tagged [crossword-clues], not [cryptic-clues]

Welcome to Puzzling, take our [tour]! Could you please provide proper attribution for this question? (e.g. link the crossword)

It is a synonym, just an uncommon one.
Entertainment is, in one definition, rather simply:

the act of entertaining

And to entertain something is:

to receive [it] and take [it] into consideration
refused to entertain our plea

Or in other words, to entertain something, such as a request, is to review it. Here, it's used as a noun, in the sense of:

an act or the process of reviewing

Matching the fact that entertainment is also a noun.

As Stiv and M Oehm point out in the comments, it could also potentially be that one definition of "review" is simply "revue", meaning:

a theatrical production consisting typically of brief loosely connected often satirical skits, songs, and dances

...which is certainly one type of entertainment.  However, personally, I still favor the first explanation: traditional (non-cryptic) crosswords would tend to clue a type of entertainment as something like "certain entertainment", "some entertainment", "one form of entertainment", etc.

To me it reads more like a compiler misspelling revue...

... and review seems to be a valid variant of revue.

@MOehm Ah, interesting, I hadn't realised that was valid! In which case, I do think it more likely to be 'revue'-related than this...

@Stiv: I didn't know it either, but looked it up just in case. The real surprise is that revue and review are exact homophones in English.

@Stiv Interesting thought!  Definitely at least plausible, but I'd expect a traditional crossword to clue something like that with an indication that it's a type of entertainment, rather than a synonym for it (it would definitely be acceptable as-is in a cryptic clue, though).

Disclaimer: the vast, vast majority of my traditional crossword experience is the NYT Crossword; it is possible that other crosswords take a different approach, though I've heard it from a constructor/setter as a general statement (see "Specificity" section): "In a standard crossword, “Drink” would never be acceptable as a clue for ICED TEA; the two are not interchangeable. (All iced teas are drinks, but not all drinks are iced teas!) At a bare minimum, you would need to say 'Certain drink,' ..."

Ha, don't assume all crossword apps operate to the same standard as the NYT! Many crossword compilers go for brevity - one-word clues - and I don't think a clue like this would be out of place in a lot of crossword sites I've seen...
